# Calculating integer overflow in C

Tags: c, integer, integer-overflow

I'm attempting to solve the following equation for x to make the if statement true. I have tried using a linear congruence equation however could not get the right answer.

I am using the assumptions that integer overflow occurs at 2^63-1, and x is of type `long`

Could someone give me a pointer with how to do this?

```
long arg1 = 1234123412341234;
long arg2 = -3456345634563456;
if(x * arg1 == arg2) {
    //true
}
```

Comment: What is the size of `long`?  What is the size of `long long`?  Also, have you looked at and learned from [How to detect integer overflow in C or C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199333/)?

Comment: Enable compiler warnings and fix the reported errors. And provide a [mcve]

Comment: `long` and `long long` are 64 bits, signed.

Answer (score 2):

First, note that signed integer overflow is undefined. Unsigned integer overflow is, however, defined. I’m not sure how much that changes the problem, but I’m going to assume unsigned integers rather than signed integers.

The problem, again, is *x* × *arg1* = *arg2*. To make the wrapping explicit, we have *x* × *arg1* ≡ *arg2* (mod 2<sup>64</sup>). If we want *x*, we just solve for it; in particular, we have *x* ≡ *arg1*<sup>−1</sup> × *arg2* (mod 2<sup>64</sup>).

The question then is how to find *arg1*<sup>−1</sup>. It happens that this is called a [modular multiplicative inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse), and when it exists (it exists iff *arg1* is relatively prime to 2<sup>64</sup>), it can be found using the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm).

Comment: In this question, arg1 is even, so is not relatively prime to  2^64, which means the inverse does not exist.  That does not necessarily mean that there is no x that solves the equation -- you need reduce the range by lcm(arg1, 2^64) to get an invertable equation, or see that there is no solution.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to take these steps:
1. -3456345634563456 + 2^64 = 18443287728074988160 (call this arg2)
2. gcd(arg1, arg2) = 2
3. Since gcd != 1, no solution to problem.

Also tried using an extended euclidian calculator but no results found. Am I missing something here?

Comment: So you can divide both arg1 and arg2 by 2, giving you an odd arg1 that you can invert (mod 2^63) and solve (mod 2^63) giving you two x values (x and x + 2^63) that will both satisfy the equation.

Comment: If LCM(arg1, 2^64) does not give an integer result then no solution exists?